# Ionic Cordova NFC is not subscribing to or capturing events

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

How can I resolve the issue in my Ionic Cordova application where it's not subscribing to the NDEF listener when using the NFC PhoneGap API

Function:

```
startNFCReading() {
console.log('Starting NFC reading...');

        if (!this.nfc) {
            console.log('NFC library not found');
            return;
        }

        this.nfc
            .enabled()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('NFC enabled');
                const attachListener = this.nfc.addNdefListener(
                    (event: any) => {
                        console.log('Successfully attached ndef listener');
                    },
                    (err: any) => {
                        console.log('Error attaching ndef listener', err);
                    }
                ).subscribe((event) => {
                        console.log('received ndef message. the tag contains: ', event);
                        console.log('decoded tag id', this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id));
                        this.getProduct(event.tag.ndefMessage);
                }
                );
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log('NFC not enabled', e);
                // Handle NFC not enabled error here, e.g., show a user-friendly message.
            });
        console.log('After subscription');

    }
```

**console output**

Starting NFC reading...

7239.d181bf1e42e46154a791.js:1 After subscription

7239.d181bf1e42e46154a791.js:1 NFC enabled

7239.d181bf1e42e46154a791.js:1 Successfully attached ndef listener

The console output indicates that it successfully attaches the NDEF listener, but it doesn't go to the subscribe event. I've tried debugging it, but the issue persists. What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It looks like you're not the only one with this issue. https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/430

Comment: Yes, have visited this thread aslo tried the solution also but the results are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, you seem to need 3 functions in the `addNdefListener` call:

`addNdefListener: function (callback, win, fail)`

So I think your first function

```
(event: any) => {
  console.log('Successfully attached ndef listener');
}
```

Is being used as the `callback`, when you want it to be used as the `win`.

Try removing the `subscribe` call and putting that function as the `callback`:

```
const attachListener = this.nfc.addNdefListener(
  (event) => {
    console.log('received ndef message. the tag contains: ', event);
    console.log('decoded tag id', this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id));
    this.getProduct(event.tag.ndefMessage);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('Successfully attached ndef listener');
  },
  (err: any) => {
    console.log('Error attaching ndef listener', err);
  });
```

Comment: this.nfc.addNdefListener() takes only two argument which are onSuccess and onFailure in my version.

Comment: Which library is that? The only one I can find anything about is https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc

Comment: Yes, I am using this library, but the documentation is very old.

Comment: It looks like the library on github is dormant (last updated 3 yearts ago). Are you getting a more up-to-date version from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm using these two NFC libraries:

@ionic-native/nfc: Version "^5.35.0"
phonegap-nfc: Version "^1.2.0"
The addNdefListener function is derived from the ionic-native/nfc library.